# Blackboard theme for iPad Keynote

Tags: ipad, icloud, keynote, font, themes

I'm creating a presentation with my MacBook Pro and Keynote.

I'm using the theme Blackboard which uses the font Chalkboard.
When I import the presentation on my iPad Mini via iCloud the default font becomes Chalkduster and the presentation is messed up.

I noticed that the font Chalkboard is present in the iPad, however it would take a lot to change all the text fonts manually.

Why does the iPad Keynote change the font? Is there a way to prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually my problem was that *Blackboard* on OSx uses *Chalkboard* while on iOS use *Chalkboard SE*.

So I had to change all the fonts form *Chalkboard* to *Chalkboard SE*.